# Is there a way to specifiy a Halide computation that operates on quartets of pixels?

Tags: halide

In Halide, is there a way to split up an input image into 2x2 quartets of pixels and implement a unique computation in each pixel of the quartet?

For example, I want to implement the following computations for each pixel in the quartet:

```
Upper left: (x + 1, y) + (x - 1, y) + (x, y + 1) + (x, y - 1)
Upper right: (x + 1, y) + (x - 1, y)
Lower left: (x, y + 1) + (x, y - 1)
Lower right: (x - 1, y - 1) + (x + 1, y - 1) + (x - 1, y + 1) + (x + 1, y + 1)
```

And I want this computational pattern to extend across the entire input image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. You can do it perhaps most directly using a `select` on `x%2==0` and `y%2==0`. Something like:

```cpp
// Sub-terms
Expr ul = in(x+1,y) + in(x-1,y) + in(x,y+1) + in(x,y-1);
Expr ur = in(x+1,y) + in(x-1,y);
Expr ll = in(x,y+1) + in(x,y-1);
Expr ul = in(x-1,y-1) + in(x+1,y-1) + in(x-1,y+1) + in(x+1,y+1);

Expr ix = x%2==0;
Expr iy = y%2==0;

out(x,y) = select(iy,
             select(ix, ul, ur),
             select(ix, ll, lr));
```

(There’s also a [multi-condition version](https://halide-lang.org/docs/namespace_halide.html#ab424bc4f6a19ef454f7c8541b2d8c890) of `select` into which you could pack this.)

If you then `unroll` the `x` and `y` dimensions of `out` each by 2, you'll get a tight loop over quartets with no control flow:

```
out.unroll(x,2).unroll(y,2);
```

This is quite similar to the patterns you see in a demosaicing algorithm, of which you can find one [here](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/apps/camera_pipe/camera_pipe_generator.cpp) in the official Halide reference apps. Inspired by that, you may also find it natural to pack your data from 2D into 3D, with the 3rd dimension being the 4 elements of a quartet:

```cpp
packed(x,y,c) = in(x+c%2, y+c/2);
```

which you may find easier to work with in some cases.